# Issue with Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm making a program that initializes the values for each employee and then it is eventually displayed. I keep having an issue with the scanner after about the 4th loop I get error `java.lang.IllegalStateException` scanner closing, any advice would be helpful.

```
for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
{
    System.out.println("For an employee who get salary enter #1.");
    System.out.println("For an employee who's hourly enter #2.");
    System.out.println("For an employee who's paid comission enter #3");
    System.out.println("For an employee who's base & comission enter #4 or 0 to quit.");
    Employees[x] = keyboard.nextInt();
    switch (Employees[x])
    {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Please enter your first name.");
            FName[x] = keyboard.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter your last name.");
            LName[x] = keyboard.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter your social security in format 111-11-1111");
            SS[x] = keyboard.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter your salary amount $.");
            Check[x] = keyboard.nextDouble();
            SalariedEmployee salariedEmployee = 
                 new SalariedEmployee( FName[x], LName[x], SS[x], Check[x] );
            employees[x] = salariedEmployee;
            break;
        case 2: 
            System.out.println("Please enter your first name.");
            FName[x] = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter your last name.");
            LName[x] = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter your social security in format 111-11-1111");
            SS[x] = keyboard.nextLine();System.out.println("Please enter your first name.");
            System.out.println("How many hours were worked?");
            Hours[x] = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println("How much paid per hour?");
            Rate[x] = keyboard.nextDouble();
            HourlyEmployee hourlyEmployee = 
            new HourlyEmployee( FName[x], LName[x], SS[x], Hours[x], Rate[x] );
            employees[x] = hourlyEmployee;
            break;
        case 3: 
            System.out.println("Please enter your first name.");
            FName[x] = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter your last name.");
            LName[x] = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter your social security in format 111-11-1111");
            SS[x] = keyboard.nextLine();System.out.println("Please enter your first name.");
            System.out.println("What was your weekly sale?");
            CommissionSales[x] = keyboard.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("What is your percentage paid commission?");
            CommissionRate[x] = keyboard.nextDouble();
           HourlyEmployee hourlyEmployee = 
            new HourlyEmployee( FName[x], LName[x], SS[x], Hours[x], Rate[x] );
            employees[x] = hourlyEmployee;
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Please enter your first name.");
            FName[x] = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter your last name.");
            LName[x] = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter your social security in format 111-11-1111");
            SS[x] = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println("What was your weekly sale?");
            CommissionSales[x] = keyboard.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("What is your percentage paid commission?");
            CommissionRate[x] = keyboard.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter your salary amount $.");
            Check[x] = keyboard.nextDouble();
            BasePlusCommissionEmployee basePlusCommissionEmployee = 
            new BasePlusCommissionEmployee( FName[x], LName[x], SS[x], CommissionSales[x], CommissionRate[x], Check[x]);
            employees[x] = basePlusCommissionEmployee;
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Where are you declaring the Scanner?
My guess is that you are closing the scanner somewhere and trying to access it.

Answer (score 1):

All of the `Scanner` methods you use will throw an `IllegalStateException` if the scanner is closed when you attempt to use them. Somewhere in your code, you likely have `keyboard.close()`. Delete this line, or move it to the end of your program, and you're golden. From the Java documentation:

> Attempting to perform search operations after a scanner has been closed will result in an IllegalStateException.